# plotly in R : setting ranges on axis with "reversed" autorange

Tags: r, plotly

I have a plotly graph in R with a reversed x-axis. I want to be able to play with its ranges. I know it is normal because by design, setting "range" turns "autorange" to "FALSE". https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-range

But I still need to play with ranges of this reversed axes. Any workarounds, anyone?

Greetings

```
library(plotly)
s <- seq(1, 8)
plot_ly(x = s, y = s) %>%
  add_trace(y = rev(s)) %>%
  layout(
     xaxis = list(range = c(3,5), autorange="reversed"), 
     yaxis = list(range = c(2, 5)))
```

Comment: can you try xaxis = list(range = c(5,3))

Comment: Unfortunately. Even with range = c(5,3), I have full range for x axis.

Comment: it's weird because it was working for me

Comment: I'm on windows. latest version of Rstudio and plotly...

Comment: try without the autorange="reserved" like in s <- seq(1, 8)
plot_ly(x = s, y = s) %>%
  add_trace(y = rev(s)) %>%
  layout(
     xaxis = list(range = c(5,3)), 
     yaxis = list(range = c(2, 5)))

Comment: As I said it's working for me, so fyi I am using plotly_3.4.3 (development version)  ggplot2_2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just retyping my comment above. Using plotly_3.4.3 (development version) and ggplot2_2.1.0. Remove `autorange="reversed"` from your code and try:

```
s <- seq(1, 8) 
plot_ly(x = s, y = s) %>% 
add_trace(y = rev(s)) %>% 
layout( xaxis = list(range = c(5,3)), yaxis = list(range = c(2, 5)))
```